# update_post_meta not working in action hook

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm having a real problem updating custom fields (within a custom post type) with data from the database.

I have a table in the database called `wp_company_profiles` with address fields (i.e. address_1, address_2). I have set custom fields for each in the admin post area with the same values. I am trying to put together a hook that will retrieve the data from the database to update the custom fields.

Below is the code, but I can't figure out what its missing.

```
function get_fields_company_profile($post_id)  {

    global $wpdb;

    if ($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )) $postid = $parent_id;

    $postid = $_GET['post'];

    $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_company_profiles WHERE pid = '$postid' " );

    if ($row) {

        // retrieve fields from database
        $address1 = $row->address_1;
        $address2 = $row->address_2;
        $postcode = $row->postcode;
        $city = $row->city;

        // update custom fields in admin area
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'address_1', $address1);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'address_2', $address2);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'postcode', $postcode);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'city', $city);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'get_fields_company_profile');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, init hook doesn't supply `$post_id` as an argument.

Secondly, you have miss-matched variable name - `$postid` & `$post_id`

Here's the revised code -

```
function get_fields_company_profile()
{
    if( 
        isset($_GET['post']) && '' != $_GET['post']
        && isset($_GET['action']) && 'edit' == $_GET['action']
        && ( !isset($_GET['post_type']) || 'post' == $_GET['post_type'] )
    ){
        global $wpdb;
        $postid = (int) $_GET['post'];

        $row = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_company_profiles WHERE pid = '$postid'" );

        if ($row)
        {
            // retrieve fields from database
            $address1 = $row->address_1;
            $address2 = $row->address_2;
            $postcode = $row->postcode;
            $city = $row->city;

            // update custom fields in admin area
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'address_1', $address1);
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'address_2', $address2);
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'postcode', $postcode);
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'city', $city);
        }
    }
}
add_action('load-post.php', 'get_fields_company_profile');
```

Comment: Thanks Shazzad. That makes a lot of sense. I knew I couldn't use init in the long term, was only using that for testing as I didn't know which hook to use at this point. The only reason I used $postid is because the query wouldn't accept $post_id, but the init hook is obviously why. Can you please suggest an action hook I should use? save_post or pre_post_update is no good as I need the hook to fire on page load. The custom fields need the data before the post is saved.

Comment: So do you want to update the postmeta from your custom table when an user is on the post edit page ? ex: "yoursite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=337&action=edit" ?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: Hook to - 'load-post.php'

Comment: Brilliant!! Solved. Thank you Shazzad, thats worked!